# Сортировка массива items без изменения массива keys в C#

Tags: c#, массивы, сортировка, index

Есть задача: "проиндексировать" некий массив keys[] без его физической модификации, то есть, нужно получить массив items[] индексов, отражающий сортировку keys. Мой вариант:

```
    static int[] ArrayIndex(int[] ar)
    {
        int[] keys= (int[])ar.Clone();
        int[] items= new int[ar.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++) items[i] = i;
        Array.Sort(keys, items);
        return items;
    } // ArrayIndex
```

Выглядит громоздко и ресурсоёмко, особенно если учесть, что у меня ar может достигать сотен мегабайт. Может быть кто-то из знатоков подскажет более изящное и эффективное решение?

Answer (score 1):

Вам не надо копировать саши сотни мегабайт, достаточно переопределить компаратор. Например

```
static int[] ArrayIndex2(int[] keys)
{   
    int[] items = new int[keys.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++) items[i] = i;    
    Array.Sort(items,(x,y)=>keys[x].CompareTo(keys[y]));
    return items;
} // ArrayIndex
```

Comment: Предложенное решение работает. При этом индексация массива из 116 млн элементов (460 Мб) требует 100 сек. "Мой" вариант с клонированием входного массива индексирует за 13.6 сек.

Answer (score 1):

Вот это альтернатива твоему решению:

```
    static int[] ArrayIndex(int[] ar)
    {
        return ar
            .Select((x, i) => new KeyValuePair<int, int>(x, i))
            .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
            .Select(x => x.Value)
            .ToArray();
    }
```

Черт его знает будет ли быстрее, но выглядит эстетичнее.

---

может я что-то и упускаю, но...

В теории можно сделать менее ресурсоемко если создать KeyValuePair где будет индекс и поинтер на оригинальный value. (через unsafe код)

В таком случае будет занимать меньше памяти. И не будет тратится время на копирование твоих 500 мегабайт. А тогда уже через Order и Select взять индексы. Это вряд ли сильно повлияет на быстродействие, зато будет экономить память.

Comment: К сожалению, приведенное решение отрабатывает 460 Мб (116 элементов для индексации) за время 140 сек, то есть худшее из трех проверенных. При этом потребляемая память тоже наибольшая (сужу по ступеньке в диспетчере задач). Подтверждается общее правило: чем решение универсальнее, тем больше всяких ресурсов оно требует.

Comment: @mai спасибо за фидбек

Comment: а идею с unsafe кодом пробовал?

Comment: Честно говоря, я unsafe еще не освоил ). Поэтому - не пробовал. Как-нибудь, если прижмет, залезу в unsafe.